# How I can convert Map to String?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana, string-formatting

This is my map:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("topicRef", "update-123456-78925-new-u1z1w3");
        params.put("parentRef", "update-123456-78925-new-u1z1w3");

        Script script = new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless",
                String.format("ctx._source.parentRef = params.parentRef; ctx._source.topicRef = params.topicRef"),
                params);
        request.setScript(script);
```

I want to convert my map into a string but I would like to change the pattern for e.g.:

```
"ctx._source.key = value;ctx._source.key = value"
```

I want to add to key value a prefix `ctx._source.key` and a suffix `" ="` (space and equal), then I would like to separate each entry with a semicolon.

Comment: You can iterate over a `Map`'s entries using `for(Map.Entry<String, Object> e : params.entrySet()) {` and then build a String from it as you like it.

Answer (score 2):

```
String formattedMap = params.entrySet().
        stream()
        .map(e -> "ctx._source." + e.getKey() + " = " + e.getValue())
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
Map<String, String> yourMap = /*...*/;
StringBuilder bob = new StringBuilder();
yourMap.forEach((key, value) -> bob.append(key).append("=").append(value).append(";"));
String result = bob.toString();
```

If necessary you could remove the last `;` on result via `String.concat()`.

Answer (score 2):

You could stream your `Map`'s entries, then use the `map` operation to map each entry to the formatted `String` and ultimately join each element with the `collect(Collectors.joining(";"))` operation.

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("topicRef", "update-123456-78925-new-u1z1w3");
params.put("parentRef", "update-123456-78925-new-u1z1w3");

String result = params.entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> String.format("%s%s%s%s", "ctx._source.", entry.getKey(), " =", entry.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(";"));

System.out.println(result);
```

Here is a link to test the code

https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/rrK

###### Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
String result = params.entrySet()
               .stream()
               .map(x -> "ctx._source." + x.getKey() + " = " + x.getValue())
               .reduce((x, y) -> x + ";" + y).get();
```

Comment: String query = params.entrySet().stream()
                .map(e -> String.format("ctx._source.%s='%s'", e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(";"));     -- I used this, that makes code more readable.